# Can't send log from Hapi-Pino to Elasticsearch

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch, hapi.js, pinojs

- I'm building server for a website use `hapi` and `hapi-pino` for logging.
- I want to analyze log (about status code, route, timestamp) for some business purpose. I use `elasticsearch` and `kibana` to do it
- Between `hapi-pino` and `Elasticsearch`, I try to use `pino-elasticsearch` to send log. However, it didn't work, elasticsearch didn't get anything
  This is my code for registering hapi-pino:

```js
const streamToElastic = PinoElasticsearch({
    index: 'api',
    type: 'log',
    consistency: 'one',
    node: 'http://elastic:changeme@localhost:9200',
    'es-version': 6,
    'bulk-size': 200,
    ecs: true
});

await server.register({
    plugin: HapiPino,
    options: {
        logPayload: true,
        prettyPrint: process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production',
        redact: {
            paths: ['req.headers', 'payload.user.password', 'payload.file'],
            remove: true
        },
        stream: streamToElastic
    }
});
```

Thanks for any helps and sorry about my poor English!

Comment: Don't know if this helps but for es 7 I was having the issue of trying to connect to elastic before it being ready and that marked the connection as dead. Make sure that your elasticsearch is up and running before trying to connect from your node app.